# Coroutine canceled when the inner flow is collected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

In this code, it seems to be canceled when the coroutine encounters a flow collected.

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    println("Hi, world!")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        innerSuspend()
        println("Bye, world!")
    }.join()
    println("task ended.")
}

suspend fun innerSuspend() {
    println("run: innerSuspend")
    innerFlow().collect {
        println("innerCallback : $it")
    }
}

suspend fun innerFlow() = callbackFlow {
    trySend("U r world?")
    awaitClose { close() }
}
```

I expected the result of above code to look something like this:

> Hi, world! 
> run: innerSuspend 
> innerCallback : U r world? 
> Bye, world! 
> task ended.

But, contrary to expectations, `Bye, world!` It is not displayed.

> Hi, world! 
> run: innerSuspend 
> innerCallback : U r world?

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Also, there is no point in calling `launch { .. }.join()`, you may as well just call the suspend function. If you do want to switch dispatchers, just use `withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { ... }` to wrap your suspend call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coroutine is not cancelled. It is still suspended, waiting for the next item from your Flow. You designed a Flow that never closes, so calling `collect()` on it will suspend forever.

You put the `close()` call inside `awaitClose { }`, as if you only want it to be closed after it is already closed, which doesn't make sense. You should just put `close()`.

```
suspend fun innerFlow() = callbackFlow {
    trySend("U r world?")
    close()
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that `Flow` would be a problem. Thank you!